# Changing image source when ID is different

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to use javascript to change the logo in my header when the background image id is for example "dark", so that the logo changes from one color to another and people can actually see the logo again. Right now what I have is this, but it doesn't seem to do the job and I am not even sure if it could even work tbh.

```
<div class="slider--image" id="dark" STYLE="background-image:  url(source1.png)">



<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on('document_change', function () {
if (document.getElementById('dark')) {
document.getElementById("main--logo").src = "new.gif";
}
});

</script>
```

So the main--logo is the id of the logo visible in my header.

The problem is, it is a full page slider and the entire background changes, so sometimes the logo needs to be black and sometimes it needs to be white. Is there a way to do it like I tried to, or maybe a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: I am targeting the ID of dark in my code, right? And then after that targeting my logo id in the header(not visible here). The slider--image class is for my css.

Comment: I am not trying to change the slide/background image itself, I am trying to change the logo based on wether my slide ID is dark or not.

Comment: For better answer please post all your HTML code

Answer (score 0):

you solution will not work as `#main--logo` is not found on your HTML

also `.src` will not work as it's not an image but a background-image

Try to use class instead of id and use jQuery function `hasClass()`

```js
$(document).on('document_change', function () {
   if ($('.slider--image').hasClass(dark)) {
       $("#main--logo").src = "new.gif";
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div class="slider--image dark" style="background-image:  url(source1.png)">

</div>
```